# Why does ECDiffieHellmanP256 work with ECDsaCng.SignData()?

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, elliptic-curve

In .NET there are two P256 curve algorithms that can be used with [CngKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngkey):

- [CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngalgorithm.ecdiffiehellmanp256) Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) key exchange
- [CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngalgorithm.ecdsap256) Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)

What confuses me is it appears to be possible to create a signature using `CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256`.

Sample code:

```cs
// create private key and data
var privateKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256);
Console.WriteLine($"privateKey: {privateKey.Algorithm} {privateKey.KeyUsage}");

// sign data
var data = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
byte[] signature;
using (var dsa = new ECDsaCng(privateKey))
{
    signature = dsa.SignData(data);
    Console.WriteLine($"Signature: {Convert.ToBase64String(signature)}");
}

// create stand-alone public key, just to be sure this is working as expected
var publicKeyBlob = privateKey.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
var publicKey = CngKey.Import(publicKeyBlob, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
Console.WriteLine($"Public key: {publicKey.Algorithm} {publicKey.KeyUsage} {Convert.ToBase64String(publicKeyBlob)}");

// verify signature
using (var dsa = new ECDsaCng(publicKey))
{
    var verified = dsa.VerifyData(data, signature);
    Console.WriteLine($"Verified: {verified}");
}
```

*output:*

```
privateKey: ECDH_P256 AllUsages
Signature: I1+Bapp8jxC7hUbTQTDTqscR9uoM/bo0OG1WVxgJUWYWq6jmW38a51JnuVRMXMKHosLOClt+AlrjiL/hG7TaqQ==
Public key: ECDH_P256 AllUsages RUNLMSAAAAC9amJDYvEJF+6HXyIhHoOiyUyu3grcH7leeuiOjMAiGbKwFoLssph+NCpY35g2dSHvNgaU11AavV/gAkPH6UPm
Verified: True
```

Just to show the similarity; if I switch to use `CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256`:

```
privateKey: ECDSA_P256 AllUsages
Signature: meQ2ywrGWCOnVCaa0bm74Z0Sj37epzSJ5bz/b0x31hGvTn8zk3hcRt5If1+r1PgoR0A1cmSBDF4QUkY0UQjPhw==
Public key: ECDSA_P256 AllUsages RUNTMSAAAADfyG3BtOqGrI63Kh+FPy6V0EmpVX/4mBSbDQ+RxEerlaQCIVq0STrl87D+Re1b+iZ7a8/+S74cHrFNILqYqLXi
Verified: True
```

---

Note that doing this the other way around -- trying to create a DH object using a DSA key -- with `new ECDiffieHellmanCng(CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256))` results in:

> ArgumentException: Keys used with the ECDiffieHellmanCng algorithm must have an algorithm group of ECDiffieHellman.Parameter name: key

This implies there is some kind of difference between the key types.

---

Is it actually safe to use ECDH keys in this way (eg: is this code generating a secure digital signature)?

Is there a benefit to using ECDSA keys over ECDH keys (other than if you explicitly didn't want to allow key exchange)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ECDiffieHellmanCng(CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256))`
> This implies there is some kind of difference between the key types.

When you try to [initialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_ECDiffieHellmanCng__ctor_System_Security_Cryptography_CngKey_) an [`ECDiffieHellmanCng`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellman?view=net-5.0) using a [`CngKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngkey?view=net-5.0) during runtime is verifies that the `CngKey` that you provided is part of a particular list of algorithms, MSDN calls them the [Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) algorithm group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellman.create?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_ECDiffieHellman_Create_System_String_), which has four valid AlgorithmGroup names `ECDH`,`ECDiffieHellman`,`ECDiffieHellmanCng`, and `System.Security.Cryptography.ECDiffieHellmanCng`, which [**all refer to the same implementation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellman.create?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_ECDiffieHellman_Create_System_String_).

When you create a `CngKey` with `CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256` you get a valid **ECDH** key who's AlgorithmGroup is `ECDH`, which is valid as a parameter to create a `ECDiffieHellmanCng` to perform key exchanges.

However, when you create a `CngKey` with `CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256` you get a key with an AlgorithmGroup of `ECDSA` which is *not* a valid AlgorithmGroup to create a `ECDiffieHellmanCng` to perform key exchanges.

The `ECDSA` AlgorithmGroup is used to denote a `CngKey` who's purpose to to perform Elliptic-curve Digital Signatures, and explicitly *not* perform key exchanges. This key can't be used with a `ECDiffieHellmanCng` to perform key exchanges because it most probably does not contain enough, valid and/or secure information to perform key exchanges with another party.

You're able to construct valid EC signatures using `ECDsaCng` with both ECDH and ECDSA `CngKey`s because they both contain enough, valid, or secure information to construct and perform a digital signatures. However, the reverse is not the same due to the limitations MSDN created when performing key exchanges, with their implementation of `ECDiffieHellmanCng`, in addition to the probable missing information/format the ECDSA `CngKey` key prevents the proper calculation of a key exchange.

We can verify this information with a short test script

```cs
CngKey ECDHKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDiffieHellmanP256);

CngKey ECDSAKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256);

Console.WriteLine(ECDHKey.Algorithm);
Console.WriteLine(ECDHKey.AlgorithmGroup);

Console.WriteLine(ECDSAKey.Algorithm);
Console.WriteLine(ECDSAKey.AlgorithmGroup);

using var ECDH = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(key: ECDHKey);

Console.WriteLine($"Signature Algorithm: {ECDH.SignatureAlgorithm}");

var ECDSA = new ECDsaCng(key: ECDHKey);

Console.WriteLine($"Signature Algorithm: {ECDSA.SignatureAlgorithm}");

ECDSA.Dispose();

ECDSA = new ECDsaCng(key: ECDSAKey);

Console.WriteLine($"Signature Algorithm: {ECDSA.SignatureAlgorithm}");

ECDSA.Dispose();

// outputs
ECDH_P256
ECDH
ECDSA_P256
ECDSA
Signature Algorithm: 
Signature Algorithm: ECDsa
Signature Algorithm: ECDsa
```

We can see that the ECDH contains the correct parameters and information to construct both a ECDSA Curve and a ECDH Curve, but the ECDSA Key can only be used with the ECDSA curve (`ECDsaCng`) because it's purpose is for performing signatures.

> Is there a benefit to using ECDSA keys over ECDH keys (other than if you explicitly didn't want to allow key exchange)?
>
> Is it actually safe to use ECDH keys in this way (eg: is this code generating a secure digital signature)?

I found a post over at [ECDSA vs ECDH](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/50878/ecdsa-vs-ecdh-vs-ed25519-vs-curve25519) that covers the nuances involved between the two, and even provided some information above as to why these keys perform different functions. Here's an excerpt that I think would be immediately useful.

> "ECDH is a key exchange method that two parties can use to negotiate a secure key over an insecure communication channel. It's a variation of the DH (Diffie-Hellman) key exchange method. ECDH stands for Elliptic-curve Diffie–Hellman. Yet ECDH is just a method, that means you cannot just use it with one specific elliptic curve, you can use it with many different elliptic curves.
>
> ECDSA is a signature algorithm that can be used to sign a piece of data in such a way, that any change to the data would cause signature validation to fail, yet an attacker would not be able to correctly re-sign data after such a change. It is a variation of DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm). ECDSA stands for Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm. Also ECDSA only describes a method which can be used with different elliptic curves."
> -[Mecki](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/104055/mecki)